# Fill an array with current day and continue backwards

Tags: javascript, jquery

so I have an array which looks like this

```
var graphData = [{ data: [[1, 1300], [2, 1600], [3, 1900], [4, 2100], [5, 2500], [6, 2200], [7, 1800]}
```

What I would like is instead of 1,2,3 etc. in the array to fill it it with the yesterdays weekday and go backwards.
 So for example today is friday, so first object would be ["thursday", 1300], next object would be ["wednesday",1600] and so on untill all weekdays are selected. And tomorrow the arrays first object would be friday, then thursday etc.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Following Logic:

```
 var d = new Date();
 var weekday = new Array(7);
 weekday[0]=  "Sunday";
 weekday[1] = "Monday";
 weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
 weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
 weekday[4] = "Thursday";
 weekday[5] = "Friday";
 weekday[6] = "Saturday";
 var decrementval;
 for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
  { 
     decrementval= Math.round((d+1)/6);
       x=d-decrementval;
      graphData[i]=weekday[Math.abs(x).getDay()];
  }
```

I Think The Above Logic Will Help You...

Comment: It doesn't, i've tried reverse looping, but what happens when the day is, lets say tuesday. The loop will go to tuesday,monday,sunday and then stop.